# Setting pipeline deployment group by variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need to set the deployment pipeline's "Deployment Group" according to some variable. This would help me to create the same pipeline for many deployment groups.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood but I'll try to help here.

I'm missing some context of your pipeline structure - is it some main .yaml file which in turn calls other .yaml files with the relevant parameters and the deployment happens accordingly or some other constellation? This context will give the idea of what you are trying to solve here.

Saying that - this might help:

1. Using [Variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) - where you already know the relevant values and can make use of it anywhere in your pipelines.
2. Using [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) - where you can set the parameters dynamically in one step of the pipeline as needed and pass it to another step of the pipeline - in this case you can evaluate the value and make decisions upon.

Let's say you have a pipeline where you need to decide to which servers/environment you should deploy to.

- The first step will be a pipeline that will make this decision and will output some parameter.
- Next - we can make use of this value in our next steps, evaluate it and trigger the next step accordingly.

In the next example - the first step will output `['WhichEnvironment.EnvChoose.TargetEnv']` which will contain the value of the target environment to deploy to - and in the next steps - it will be evaluated to decide which step to run - notice the parameters are hard coded as we cannot pass it as variable - as mentioned in Azure docs above.

> Parameters are only available at template parsing time.

### Example

```
stages:
- stage: HelmsmanDryRun
  condition: succeeded()
  
  displayName: Helmsman Dry Run
  jobs:
    - template: kubernetes/helmsman-pr-validate.yml@pipeline-templates
      parameters:
        region: eu-west-1
    
- stage: HelmsmanApplyDev
  dependsOn: HelmsmanDryRun
  condition: and(eq(dependencies.HelmsmanDryRun.outputs['WhichEnvironment.EnvChoose.TargetEnv'],'dev'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  displayName: Helmsman Apply Dev
  jobs:
    - template: kubernetes/helmsman-pr-deploy.yml@pipeline-templates
      parameters:
        targetEnvironment: dev
        region: eu-west-1

- stage: HelmsmanApplyQA
  dependsOn: HelmsmanDryRun
  condition: and(eq(dependencies.HelmsmanDryRun.outputs['WhichEnvironment.EnvChoose.TargetEnv'],'qa'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  displayName: Helmsman Apply QA
  jobs:
    - template: kubernetes/helmsman-pr-deploy.yml@pipeline-templates
      parameters:
        targetEnvironment: qa
        region: eu-west-1
```

Hopefully this gave you some direction with what you are looking for.

Comment: if I understand correctly, I'll make a condition for each environment, right? Is there a way to just "fill" the targetEnvironment from a variable?

Comment: As far as I remember - parameters cannot be set as variables - as **Parameters are only available at template parsing time.** so the value should be known ahead.

Another way is to set parameters block at the beginning of the .yaml:

`parameters:
- name: targetEnvironment
  displayName: Target Environment
  values:
  - dev
  - prod
`
So a manual triggering of the pipeline will ask the user for the value.